# Add image to backoffice attribute for the type CsTicket

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I have attribute priority which is enum type in CsTicket type and my requirement is to show the different images of low high and medium with the status of the ticket like arrow .
Can anyone suggest how I can do it .

Expecting the arrow to appear based upon the selection of status.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here I want to show that image as I don't have any code to show as of now can you suggest how we can add any static image that should appear after changing the priority,